# Having trouble with aligning an iFrame in HTML5

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe, vertical-alignment

Now I have made a website, and I have integrated google maps into it.  Now I am havign trouble with centering Google maps on the web page.

Here is my code:

```
 <iframe width="640"
            height="480"
            align="middle"
            frameborder="0"
            scrolling="no"
            marginheight="0"
            marginwidth="100"
            margin-top:100px;
            margin-left:140px;
           src="https://maps.google.ca/?ie=UTF8&amp;t=h&amp;ll=49.894634,-97.119141&amp;spn=27.26845,56.25&amp;z=4&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use `margin:auto` for the left and right of the iframe or the div its in.

Comment: I am actually just learning HTML 5 right now, what do you mean about the left and the right of the iframe?

Comment: If you want it centered in the page just put `margin-left:auto; margin-right;` and that would center that object in its parent object. So you could put the margins on the top parent object and the whole section would be centered.

Comment: AHhh, I got it, thank you so much!  I just went to the parent like you said, and that fixed my problem.  Again, thanks.